# Make Subsequent urls retain query_vars.

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that allows me to use custom templates on my WP site based of a given url.

```
//* Create Variables for URL Templates
function sjc_add_query_vars($vars) {
return array('template') + $vars;
}
add_action('query_vars', 'sjc_add_query_vars',10,1);

//* Load Cutstom Page Templates by URL
function sjc_template($template) {
global $wp;
if ($wp->query_vars['template']=='basic') {
global $post;
$posttype = get_post_type($post->ID);
return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-'. $posttype .'-basic.php';
}
else {
return $template;
}
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'sjc_template', 99 );
```

This works great. The problem is that if you click any links off that page the url reverts and the default template is used. So, is there a way to make any links on the custom template pages keep using that custom template?

Comment: I would rather do it with PHP but for now I was able to do it with JS using this script: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '?template=basic';
});
});

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options. Create a search results template that retains the variables is perhaps the most sane way to do it, however you could do something like write a cookie, store them in session or...

Generally speaking, WP "expects" you to use a search results template file. That file would retain the query_vars.

Comment: I looked at all the documents I could find about using search results templates but none of them helped. The Query Vars are already loading a custom template. But I need it to stay in that template if the user clicks links on that page. So for instance if the user goes to www.example.com/?template=basic and clicks a link to www.example.com/next/ it should take them to www.example.com/next/?template=basic